# jQuery Tree plugin jstree first time use

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get the jQuery tree plugin working with a simple example.
Following the example on the front page
http://www.jstree.com/

Im getting an error that might be pretty simple or possibly a path issue.  However, its happening in the event handler.

*Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'select_node'*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/jstree/themes/default/style.min.css" />

<script src="assets/jstree/jstree.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


    $(function () {

            //create tree instance
            $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree();

            // bind to events triggered on the tree
            $('#jstree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
                console.log(data.selected);
            });

            //interact with the tree
            $('button').on('click', function () {
                $('#jstree').jstree(true).select_node('child_node_1');
                $('#jstree').jstree('select_node', 'child_node_1');
                $.jstree.reference('#jstree').select_node('child_node_1');
            });

        });

</script>
        <div id="jstree">
            <!-- in this example the tree is populated from inline HTML -->
            <ul>
              <li>Root node 1
                <ul>
                  <li id="child_node_1">Child node 1</li>
                  <li>Child node 2</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>Root node 2</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        <button>demo button</button>
```

Comment: You have no element with `#jstree_demo_div` as called in the first line by `$('#jstree_demo_div').jstree();` for starters

Comment: Can you providea a jsfiddle?

Comment: I think changing `$('#jstree_demo_div').jstree();` to `$('#jstree').jstree();` will make it work.

Comment: Thank you.  I was starring at it too long.  Cant believe it was that simple.